# Xdebug not creating log files

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

Looking for some advice. Changed servers and I have setup Xdebug. PhpStorm detects it enabled, so does PHP, although I cannot get it to work.

(Firewall port opened, my firewall disabled, settings all configured, but I am getting nothing)

In order to identify the issue, I need to be able to see the Log of Xdebug, but I cannot get it to output anything. I tried it without a log file, then I have also created a log file and given Apache access to it, but still nothing.

I am running **CentOS 8**
Apache - **Log_Debug enabled**
Running on **php7.3**

**PHP - track_erorr enabled.**

**/opt/plesk/php/7.3/etc/php.d/50-xdebug.ini**

```
; Enable xdebug extension module
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPStorm"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_host=123.123.123.123
```

*(IP has been changed for obvious reasons)*

Can anyone tell me why I cannot get Xdebug to write out any errors or connection attempts to: `/tmp/xdebug.log`

Here is my phpinfo() debug info:

[image]

Comment: XDEBUG 3 has changed quite a bit specially in the config. Checkout the [Upgrade Notes](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide)

Comment: But I think if you set `xdebug.log = "Some/path/to/a/file.txt"` it will get you logging

Comment: You could also add `xdebug.mode =develop,debug` to activate the step debugging mode, in fact this may be all you need to get the debugger working

Comment: @DaveHamilton **Use Xdebug 3 config parameters** -- just like your screenshot says.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, on one of our developers machines it wouldn't stop at a breakpoint or work at all and we couldn't get the log to work either. He was running PHPStorm and tried debugging code on a Vagrant/Homestead VM environment using XDebug 3.1.2. Setting the line `xdebug.mode=develop,debug` did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I didn't noticed Xdebug has updated its self.
After removing all previous reference i re-setup the the debug.ini
(I dont store custom ini settings in php.ini i reference them correctly)

Here is my updated xdebug.ini This works by using the browser Plug-in to enable to the Debugger mode

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.client_host = 123.123.123.132
xdebug.client_port = 9000
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms = 200
xdebug.force_display_errors = 1
xdebug.force_error_reporting = 1
xdebug.idekey = PHPStorm
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug.log 
xdebug.log_level = 7
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.output_dir = /tmp
```

All default settings can be found here: https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/xdebug.ini

Comment: You should be using a port other than 9000, other things use that now and XDEBUG has suggested 9003 instead to stop conflicts, in fact 9003 is the default so you could remove the `xdebug.client_port = 9000` line